# Ruby cannot find 'bundler/setup'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1.0 on my Ubuntu machine. In my rails app -> config/boot.rb , there is a `require 'bundler/setup'` statement, however ruby cannot find this `'bundler/setup.rb'`, I have tried to locate this file, and this file exists in the folder `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb`, But when I run `$locate bundler/setup.rb`, there is nothing coming out. It is just so weird...

Comment: Are you sure you're running ruby 1.9.2 when you try to start your app? `ruby -v`

Comment: yep, I just deleted ruby totally, and re-installed ruby, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the index `locate` uses, you need to run `updatedb`. On Ubuntu there are cron jobs, that run it from time to time, but to find newly created files, you have to run in manually.

About the real question: You ruby installation was broken, so reinstalling fixed it. Next time you can use `gem env` to check if the paths match the paths on disk and move the files.